# oracle SQLPLUS escape the & character

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

As I find in the oracle doc,

```
SET ESCAPE:
 Defines an escape character you can use before the substitution character. The escape character instructs SQL*Plus to treat the substitution character as an ordinary character rather than as a request for variable substitution. The default escape character is a backslash (\).

SET DEFINE:
 Defines the substitution character (by default the ampersand "&") and turns substitution on and off.
```

before my query, should I do like this?:

```
SET DEFINE off
select 'A&B' from dual;
SET DEFINE on
```

The use of set escape on is it necessary in my case?

Comment: By setting define off, you have switched off the substitution variable detection. So no, you would not need to escape the ampersand in this instance.

Comment: Thanks @Boneist :)